# How to use Foreach and show the infowindow with Data title and tag

Tags: reactjs

I made a project with Kakao API, and I have a problem.

This is my marker Data

```
const markerdata =[
    {
      title: "클럽에반스",
      tag: "재즈바",
      lat: 37.55033897015321,
     lng: 126.9229336137093, 
    },
    {
      title: "치차티클럽",
      tag : "루프탑",
      lat: 37.57109940534566,
      lng: 127.01135026952784, 
    },
    {
      title: "TRVR Cafe",
      tag: "카페",
      lat:37.53838839800507, 
      lng: 126.99353635603627,
    },
    {
      title:"용용선생",
      tag:"맛있다",
      link:"https://goo.gl/maps/tJKczRUfPTGRiv466",
      lat:37.55939806463767, 
      lng: 127.03980732534552,
    },
  ];
```

And I use forEach

```
markerdata.forEach((el) => {
        // 마커를 생성합니다
        const marker = new window.kakao.maps.Marker({
          //마커가 표시 될 지도
          map: map,
          //마커가 표시 될 위치
          position: new window.kakao.maps.LatLng(el.lat, el.lng),
          //마커에 hover시 나타날 title

        });
        
        let a = el.title;
        var infowindow = new window.kakao.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: a, // 인포윈도우에 표시할 내용
        });
```

I want to show markerdata title, tag, but it only shows title.

And I made the array to show that data, but it doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: So you using reactJs and you wanna print out your array data to frontend? If so - use `.map` instead of `foreach`. Inside your `return` (functional component), of a `render() return` if using a class component, run `markerdata.map((item) => <div>{item.title} {item.tag}</div>`. You can customize the returning code html as you like - its only an example. TBH i am confused why you even using this method of yours with windows and all... any reason?

Comment: First I find the hint of my project was using forEach...
So I use forEach too.